# SQL - count without group by? I need to use two ids for a join

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I thought I could count a column and add it as a column as I can with a sum but I get an error about having to group by / having.  An example of what I want...

Initial table...

```
 Global ID    Local ID   Name       Role
 100          1          Andy       Manager
 100          2          Andy       Manager
 100          1          John       Co-Manager
 200          1          Andy       Co-Manager
 200          2          John       Manager
 200          2          Mike       Manager
```

I then want to add a column that counts the number of Manager in each group / local pairing...

```
 Global ID    Local ID   Name       Role         Manager Count
 100          1          Andy       Manager      1
 100          2          Andy       Manager      1    
 100          1          John       Co-Manager   0
 200          1          Andy       Co-Manager   0
 200          2          John       Manager      2
 200          2          Mike       Manager      2
```

I tried just joining the two tables on the global / local ID and then adding a column for count of the Role.  The problem is that I get an error about grouping / having by but I don't want to group anything.  I just want to add the column and still have the same number of rows.  Any way around this?

FYI - for the last two rows, the last column has 2 because John and Mike are on the same group / local ID

Comment: Which DBMS? What have you tried that's not working?

Comment: I added to the title - it's Sybase IQ

I just tried - count( role ) as a new column while joining the two tables

Comment: count(*) is only work without group by.

Comment: So what other options do I have for counting?  Seems like I should be able to do it and sum() works as expected.  Note - I also had to adjust the second table for a typo for manager count

Comment: @AndyD I have tagged your question with the appropriate DBMS. Please add this information into the tags rather than question title.

Comment: Any basic SQL reference will tell you that `COUNT` requires a `GROUP BY`. There is no exception to that requirement. If you have to obtain a count, you'll need to use a sub-query that has the `COUNT` with a `GROUP BY` the ID, and then `JOIN` that sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your definition of a group is a unique combination of [global_id, local_id]. If that is the case you do want to `group by` those two values, and do a count, where the role is `Manager`. But because you want other columns from the original table, you must do that count within an inline view, and then join back to the original table, like so:

```
select t.*, v.mgr_in_grp
  from tbl t
  left join (select global_id, local_id, count(*) as mgr_in_grp
               from tbl
              where role = 'Manager'
              group by global_id, local_id) v
    on t.global_id = v.global_id
   and t.local_id = v.local_id
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb3ace/2/0

Notice that there is a difference on row 3, as compared to your expected output.

John, Co-manager at global_id and local_id 100 and 1, respectively, belongs to a pair that has a manager in that combination (Andy, your first row). So the count appears should be 1.

Comment: Thanks!  I think i was over thinking it but yeah this does it.